# Out of Memory Exception at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal but no memory leak

Tags: .net, out-of-memory

Am getting a very occasional crash with the following trace:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal(IntPtr hdc)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs.get_Graphics()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackColor(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle rectangle, Color backColor)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle rectangle, Color backColor, Point scrollOffset)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle rectangle)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer, Boolean disposeEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmEraseBkgnd(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

As you can see theres none of my code in the trace so i'm finding it very hard to find the cause. Google searches seem inconclusive but generally point to a GC handle leak somewhere but following the most recent crash my memory usage was:

```
Handle count:16,283, 
Private Bytes:995,440K, 
Virtual Bytes:1,628,208K, 
Working Set:866,892K, 
GC Heap Size:158,841K, 
GDI Objects:402, 
User Objects:1,607
```

Which does not seem out of the ordinary. Also, I regularly use .net memory profiler to manage leaks.

Unfortunately my app is quite large with many windows so my first question would be: How can I identify which window is causing all the pain?

and then of course my second question would be: If there is no handle leak, what is causing the exception!?

**Edit:**

Sorry I can't post any code: Its a massive codebase and the exceptions arent exactly giving me any clues as to which part may be the problem.

I read about there being a 10,000 limit on handles but this app has historically always run fine with 15,000 so I assumed the limit was on something else: GDI handles or user objects maybe?

Just to make sure, I checked and the handles are not being leaked as they are all assigned at startup and do not increase with usage.

Let me modify my question: Given this information, what should the next course of action be? I have process Explorer installed and have succeeded in getting a full memory dump from one of the crashes but really dont have experience in using either to diagnose this kind of problem (until now .net memory profiler has been enough)

Comment: You expect us to *guess* what your code is doing wrong? That's a lot more difficult than if you just post it.

Comment: [Mark Russinovich](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx): "[a]ny process that has more than a ten thousand handles open at any given point in time is likely either poorly designed or has a handle leak". Note that an "out of memory" exception doesn't necessarily mean you're out of *memory*; this error code is used several times in the Win32 API to indicate you're out of *resources*. You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to quickly check for duplicates.

Comment: The handle count is *way* too high.  Not sure how you managed to get it past 10,000, that's the normal quota for a process afaik.  Something is leaking badly though.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) Please just edit your question to provide additional information or clarity. Additionally, you can leave comments under individual answers (using the 'add comment' link). Answers are reserved for just that, answers - not replies to others.

Comment: The next step is to reduce the number of handles that you have open. Regardless of what the hard limit is imposed by Windows, you have *way* too many for a normal application. That you're getting exceptions as a result is hardly unexpected. As Femaref suggests, look for places where you're creating GDI+ objects (such as Brushes, Pens, etc.) but not disposing them. Best practice is to wrap the creation and use in a `using` statement, which will automatically handle disposing the object as soon as you're done using it. Check your `Paint` event handlers; that's the most likely site of a leak.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably assigning Brushes or Pens and aren't disposing of them - That consumes GDI handles and at some point, all of them are used and you get an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Check it with JetBrains DotTrace or Task Manager. (In task manager add GDI-Count).

Answer (score 0):

Since we can't see the code, here's a possibility for that error. It just happened to me.

Make sure you're calling the correct method. I've tried to get a `Graphics` object from HDC and I was supposed to choose the method overload that takes an HWND instead. It's pretty easy to fall for these mistakes here since there's no type checking whatsoever between these handles.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but in case someone else ends up here, but there's a Hotfix that got released:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2650146/fix-outofmemoryexception-exception-when-you-use-a-graphics-object-to-p

> FIX: OutOfMemoryException exception when you use a graphics object to
> paint in a .NET Framework 3.5-based Windows Forms application Applies
> to: .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1
>
> Symptoms
> Consider the following scenario:
>
> - You create a Microsoft .NET
>   Framework 3.5-based graphics-intensive application on a computer that
>   is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2.
> - The application uses
>   the graphics device interface (GDI).
> - You create a graphics object, and
>   then use it to paint. In this scenario, you may experience an
>   OutOfMemoryException exception. Additionally, you receive the
>   following error message:
>
> Exception type: System.OutOfMemoryException Message: Out of memory.
>
> When you debug this issue, you receive a stack trace that resembles
> the following:
>
> at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal(IntPtr hdc)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs.get_Graphics()

To resolve:

> A supported hotfix is now available from Microsoft. However, it is
> intended to correct only the problem that this article describes.
> Apply it only to systems that are experiencing this specific problem.
>
> To resolve this problem, contact Microsoft Customer Support Services
> to obtain the hotfix. For a complete list of Microsoft Customer
> Support Services telephone numbers and information about support
> costs, visit the following Microsoft website:
> http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/?ws=support